# CTRL+D not sending EOF consistently

Tags: python, macos, eof

I am using OSX terminal to run a python script, which reads in an arbitrary number of lines of stdin and then processes it.

The problem is CTRL+D is not working consistently. Sometimes it successfully sends the EOF but sometimes it just adds "^D" to my command line and when I press CTRL+D again, more ^D appears.

Why is that so? The behaviour is not consistent even when using the same input.

Comment: You question lacks needed information.  If you are hitting ^D while running a python program with an input() statement, then I suspect that the different behavior depends on whether you hit it while the program is executing input or while the program is processing the input after input() returns.

Comment: I read it using sys.stdin.readlines(). The program first reads the input before processing anything. I hit CTRL+D right after I finish typing the input.

Comment: Might something be taking the terminal out of canonical mode?

Comment: What do you mean? The behavior is inconsistent even when using the same terminal with the same inputs. First time it's working the second time it's not and then the third time it's ok again